# What does the token %1$s in WordPress represent

Tags: php, categories

I have seen the token %1$ and similar ones more often in the WordPress code lately, but I can't figure out what it means. Here an example:

```
sprintf( __( '%1$s is deprecated. Use %2$s instead.' ),
```

Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: it is used by `sprintf`, look here : https://secure.php.net/sprintf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Read the [PHP docs on sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

- `%s` is just a placeholder for a string
- `%d` is just a placeholder for a number

So an example of sprintf would look like this:

```
$variable = sprintf(
    'The %s ran down the %s',   // String with placeholders
    'dog',      // Placed in the first %s placeholder
    'street'    // Placed in the second %s placeholder
);
```

Which will return a string to our variable `$variable`:

> The **dog** ran down the **street**

By numbering the placeholders it's both a developer-friendly way to quickly tell which following string will be placed where. It also allows us to reuse a string. Let's take another example with numbered placeholders:

```
$variable = sprintf(
    'The %1$s ran down the %2$s. The %2$s was made of %3$s',    // String with placeholders
    'dog',      // Will always be used in %1$s placeholder
    'street',   // Will always be used in %2$s placeholder
    'gravel'    // Will always be used in %3$s placeholder
);
```

Which will return a string to our variable `$variable`:

> The **dog** ran down the **street**. The **street** was made of **gravel**

Finally, the [`__()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) function let's us translate strings passed to it. By passing `__()` placeholders, and then passing that whole string to `sprintf()`, we can translate whatever is passed to the translating function allowing us to make our string and application a bit more dynamic.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a WordPress thing, it's a PHP thing. `%1$s`, `%2$s`, etc., are placeholders for variables in a formatted string returned by [`sprintf()`](https://secure.php.net/sprintf) (or printed by [`printf()`](https://secure.php.net/printf)).

The `1$` indicates it's the *first* variable, `2$` would be the second, and so forth. The `s` indicates it's a *string* variable. Other options exist (eg, `d` would indicate an integer).

The example you give is incomplete: it's certainly something like this in its entirety:

```
sprintf( __( '%1$s is deprecated. Use %2$s instead.' ),
$string_1,
$string_2 );
```